# Why is angular saying my object can be null when creating in ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngoninit

Creating a form in the component:

```
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]),
    })
  }

}
```

In html, I perform value input checks

```
<div *ngIf="form.get('email').touched && form.get('email').invalid" class="validation">
  <small *ngIf="form.get('email').errors.required">Enter Email</small>
  <small *ngIf="form.get('email').errors.email">Enter valid Email</small>
</div>
```

For every line where the form IDEA occurs, swears

```
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'
```

I understand that this is due to the fact that the creation of the object takes place in ngOnInit. Put a "?" sign everywhere and IDEA stops swearing:

```
<div *ngIf="form.get('email')?.touched && form.get('email')?.invalid" class="validation">
  <small *ngIf="form.get('email')?.errors.required">Enter Email</small>
  <small *ngIf="form.get('email')?.errors.email">Enter valid Email</small>
</div>
```

But how correct is it?

Maybe there is a more correct solution to this problem?

Maybe I'm creating the Form Group object incorrectly?

Comment: why are you creating this on init? Just create it when you declare it. Nothing is dynamic so using onInit is pointless

Comment: You can create `form` while declaring it or use optional chaining (`? `) like `*ngIf="form?.get('email')?.touched && ...."`

Comment: That is, the use of "?" is not a bad code style?

Comment: why would using `?` be "bad code style"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing logically wrong with the code for checking the control validations using the safe navigation operator, as it has been in TypeScript since version 3.7.

One other thing I noticed is the repeated gets for the controls in the HTML.

Move the repeated `this.form.get(..)` calls into getters like below:

```
get email() {
  return this.form.get('email');
}

get password() {
  return this.form.get('password');
}
```

and the HTML script will be tidier as shown with the ? operator still consistent:

```
<div *ngIf="email?.touched && email?.invalid" class="validation">
  <small *ngIf="email?.errors.required">Enter Email</small>
  <small *ngIf="email?.errors.email">Enter valid Email</small>
</div>
```